# Ionic 2 Accordion Group - Showing empty ion-cards where it should not show cards at all if data is not available

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, accordion

I am trying to create accordion group in ionic 2. Upon click it should expand and show "ion-cards" with if data is available. Problem is when I click to expand, it shows empty ion-card where I don't want it cards show at all if there is no data.

Below is my code:

Home.html

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="toggleGroup(item)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(item)}">


  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon [name]="item.symbol" color="dark" item-left></ion-icon>
    <h2 [innerHTML]="item.title" class="Ride" item-left></h2>
    <ion-icon color="dark" item-right [name]="isGroupShown(item) ? 'remove' : 'add'"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-card *ngIf="isGroupShown(item)">
    <ion-item>{{item.description}}
      <button fixed ion-button item-right clear (click)="goToItemDetails()" class="button">View</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>

</ion-list>
```

Home.ts

```js
items = [{
    title: "Ride",
    symbol: "car",
    description: "Need a ride"

  },
  {
    title: "Meal",
    symbol: "restaurant",

  },
  {
    title: "Child-Care",
    symbol: "logo-reddit",
    icon: "add"
  },
];

shownGroup = null;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

}

toggleGroup(group) {
  if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
    this.shownGroup = null;
  } else {
    this.shownGroup = group;
  }
};
isGroupShown(group) {
  return this.shownGroup === group;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the screenshot:
[Here, Ion-card shouldn't be visible or shown when there is no data. On toggle, it should only show card for that category if it is present else nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW5V1.png)

Comment: Am I get your question right? when `items` has no data you don't want to show `ion-list`?

Comment: @RezaRahmati Added screenshot from the app. When I click on category, it should only show card if data is present else upon toggle it should be empty and not generate blank ion-cards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more condition to make card visible, for example

```
  <ion-card *ngIf="isGroupShown(item) && item.description && item.description !== ''">
    <ion-item>{{item.description}}
      <button fixed ion-button item-right clear (click)="goToItemDetails()" class="button">View</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: added condition for ion-description but still showing the blank card.

Comment: add `{{isGroupShown(item)}} {{item.description !== ''}}` on line before ion-card, to investigate the values and see if both are true when it shows the empty card

Comment: also I edit my answer, because i see that you have items with no description at all

Comment: tried but condition didn't work.. Guess I have to find another solution

Comment: @JBhatt Did you add this `{{isGroupShown(item)}} {{item.description !== ''}}` to your code to realize what is going on there?